# Force Firefox to open new tab and not new window

Tags: windows, firefox, process, tabs

My application sometimes opens URLs in a browser. I do this with `Process.Start("http://www.example.com")`.

My default browser is Firefox. I notice that if the above code runs when no Firefox window is active, each URL (I open several URLs in one go) is opened in its own window.

However, if a Firefox window is already open, the URLs all get opened as new tabs.

How can I make it always open as tabs? Always as windows? Open a single new window and make everything a tab in that?

Answer (score 1):

Because command-line arguments differ between browsers, to do this successfully you would need to launch Firefox explicitly and pass in the appropriate parameters. You would have to create a similar solution for each additional browser you wanted to drive.

If this is something you're doing just for yourself or in an environment where you have some control over what's installed on user machines, then it may be solvable. But if it's a general purpose program meant to work on any Windows PC, then it probably isn't practical.

For firefox, the command line arguments are:

```
-new-tab URL
```

> Opens URL in a new tab.

```
-new-window URL
```

> Opens URL in a new window.